# Regarding Gaussian integrals, I'm confused about how you combine completing the square and differentiating under the integral sign.

Tags: gaussian-integral

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I have done some googling but with no luck. I'm not sure how to explain exactly so I'll just write the maths.

Is this statement true?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2*e^{-(x-b)^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$$

Or is this statement true?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-b)^2*e^{-(x-b)^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$$

Or are neither? Basically does the index power have to match what the multiplying variable is or not? If that makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Neither. Both integrals are divergent.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Sorry though I just realised I forgot my negatives while trying to work out the math's formatting. Are they still divergent if that is the case? I have edited it so it displays correctly.

Comment: No, in that case neither integrals are divergent and $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x - b)^2e^{-(x - b)^2}\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2$.

Comment: Thank you so much!